# How to deal SwiftUI background tap recognition bugs on iPad?

Tags: swiftui

I've had a number of different yet all similar bugs related to the view overlay presentation in SwiftUI on the iPad. Specifically, what I am aware of, this relates to the following modifiers:

*.popover, .confirmationDialog, and .contextMenu*

The issue is that while any of these modifiers are active, **tapping on elements in the background**, which supposed to be disabled as even hinted by SwiftUI changing button tint color to gray, **will activate those elements** additionally leading to further issues.

Here is sample view which exemplifies the problem:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showPopover = false
    @State var showConfirmation = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                    Text("Inside popover.")
                        .padding()
                }
                .confirmationDialog("Confirm", isPresented: $showConfirmation) {
                    Button("Option 1") {
                        
                    }
                    Button("Option 2") {
                        
                    }
                }
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Context Button") {
                        
                    }
                }
            
            Button("Try Me!") {
                print("Button was tapped.")
            }
            .padding()
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button("Toggle Popover") {
                    showPopover.toggle()
                }
                Button("Toggle Confirmation") {
                    showConfirmation.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Basically, if you open either popper or confirmation dialog and then tap on any other button, that button will activate.

**Additional Issue:**
If you tap popover button while confirmationDialog is open, or any other combination, of course that will trigger the popover, but that action also prints an error in console.

The popover will be called but not presented. in the case of this view, you have to tap popover button 2 more times to recover from that error, but in my project I am not able to recover unless the whole view is refreshed.

This issue has been reported before in various places for a while, including submitting bug report to Apple.

Any way to get around this? Just seems like a major issue in these components.

PS: These issues do not seem to be present on iPhone.

Comment: Hi! I've tried the sample code and couldn't reproduce the issues you've described. That said, I'm still on iOS16, could that be a factor?

Comment: Not able to reproduce either. Please detail the device and versions you are using. The popover fills the screen on an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 16.4, which suggests you must be using quite a different device. And are you trying it on a real device, simulator or preview?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the tests were done on iPad, as that is primary device I develop for. Indeed though this does not seem to be present on iPhone. Also iOS 16.

Answer (score 0):

OK, managed to reproduce on an iPad (10th Generation) simulator running iPadOS 16.4 with Xcode 14.3.1.

As a workaround, you can apply a mask over the main content when a popover or confirmation popup is showing. This can either be done with a layer in a ZStack, or just with an overlay, if it covers the areas that matter:

```swift
        VStack {
            // content as before
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay {
            if showPopover || showConfirmation {
                Color.white.opacity(0.001)
            }
        }
```